# How to edit discord embed... discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed, edit

I have question about my Embed. I have embed where users can get role with reactions. Problem is there that I want to add one more role but I don't want to ping again all roles because I'am using Carl-bot for those reactions. My question is how can I edit that embed without losing those reactions so I don't have to ping all roles again.
I've tried to create command

```
if message.content.startswith("embededit"):
      channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
      message = await bot.fetch_message(MESSAGE_ID)
      await message.edit(embed=embedEdit)
```

but it types that fetch_message doesn't exist or so. Thanks for any help!
PS, I don't use bot.command because I don't know why but it doesn't work for me....

Comment: It might be more accurate to have the post title be about your issue with getting fetch_message() to work, because the issue is not actually in editing the embed, even though that is the end goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FinnE pointed out, your issue is with `fetch_message()`. You need to do `await channel.fetch_message(MESSAGE_ID)`.

```py
if message.content.startswith("embededit"):
      channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
      message = await channel.fetch_message(MESSAGE_ID)
      await message.edit(embed=embedEdit)
```